# Recreate LocalDB in the App_Data folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I replaced the auto-created `aspnet-myproject-20130130223621.mdf` and it's ldf files with the files from another project. It didn't work so I deleted these two files and hope the Asp.Net can re-create these two files. I always get the following error Exception in the following function.

1. Is it possible to replace the auto-generated Sql server localDB files with existed database files?
2. How to let Asp.net recreate these database files?

Exception on:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
    LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
}
```

Exception message:

> {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}

InnerException message:

> {"Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\nick\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\App_Data\aspnet-MyProject-20130130223621.mdf' as database 'aspnet-MyProject-20130130223621'."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your SQL Server Management studio and connect to LocalDB. You'll see that your Database is still there. Delete it from there and .NET will re-generate your database again.

Comment: What's the `Server name` when connecting to localdb?

Comment: You can see it in your `ConnectionString` under `Data Source=stuff`. It's probably `(LocalDb)\v11.0`

Comment: FYI - when you drop the LocalDB databases in SQL Server Management Studio, you'll get an 'unable to open the physical file' error message since the .mdf file obviously doesn't exist.  However, the operation still removes the DB from LocalDb, which clears the issue.